# How to display comma separated values in a select box when another select box is selected in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, input

I have a `selectbox` like below, when this select box is selected the value inside dataprice is inserted in an input textbox,

```js
$('.selectProduct1').on('change', function() {
  $('.regularPrice1')
    .val(
      $(this).find(':selected').data('price1')
    );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select selectProduct1" name="university1" id="university1">

  <option>Select </option>


  <option data-price1="123" data-price2="c1,c2,c3,c4" value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
  <option data-price1="456" data-price2="c1,c2,c3,c4" value="test 2">Test 2</option>


</select>

<input type="number" name="fee1" id="fee1" value="" class="form-control regularPrice1">
```

That is working fine, now I want the comma separated values inside the select option to display in another `selectbox`, is that possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#university1').on('change', function() {
      $('#fee1').val($("#university1 option:selected").data('price1'));
      var Price2val=$("#university1 option:selected").data('price2');
      var arr = Price2val.split(',');
      $('#selectProduct2').html('<option seleted disabled>select</option>');
      jQuery.each(arr, function(index, item) {
        $('#selectProduct2').append('<option value="'+item+'">'+item+'</option>');
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select selectProduct1" name="university1" id="university1">
  <option selected disabled>Select </option>
  <option data-price1="123" data-price2="c1,c2,c3,c4" value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
  <option data-price1="456" data-price2="c1,c2,c3,c4,c5" value="test 2">Test 2</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="fee1" id="fee1" value="" class="form-control regularPrice1">
<select class="form-control select selectProduct2" name="selectProduct2" id="selectProduct2">
   <option selected disabled>Select </option>
</select>
```

**Please try this code.**

Comment: what i want is, the comma separated value in data-price2 to be displayed in another selectbox

Comment: @TBC please check again i have change code